# CPU Core Configuration for Go Programs Running in Docker

Tags: docker, go, cpu

I got confused in two question:

1. Suppose my computer has 4 cores, and I want to run 4 Docker containers on it, each running a Go server. I want to ensure that each container uses a ***separate*** core. How should I configure Go or Docker to achieve this?
2. How can I verify that the 4 Docker containers are indeed running on 4 different cores?

Comment: Normally you don't worry about this at all.  The Linux kernel takes responsibility for allocating CPU time to processes, which can include switching from one process to another on the same core if there's idle time.  If you have multiple Go applications, the system will work fine if each application can use any core and schedules multiple goroutines as the Go runtime sees fit.

Comment: Use [the `--cpuset-cpus` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources) for docker run.